# Выбор архитектуры для смешанного сериализатора

Tags: c#, ооп, highload

Имеется система которая парсит здоровенный XLSX файл. Исторически сложилось так, что все данные раскладывались по различным таблицам и сохранялись в БД.

Сейчас данных стало слишком много и селекты из БД проходят слишком медленно (не смотря на то что мы не используем ORM, а формируем запросы напрямую в БД и сам сериализатор моделек работает максимально оптимально).

Мы реализовали бинарное сохранение данных (просто формируем byte[] и записываем в БД). Такой способ оказался почти в 10 раз быстрее. Постепенно решено отказываться от старого способа, за исключением данных необходимых для обработки средствами SQL (например формирование отчетов).

При выпиливании сталкнулся со следующей проблеммой. Поскольку бинарный сериализатор работал не везде а только в некоторых частях системы. Выяснилось что часть данных просто не сохранялись. (Но в отдельных таблицах эти данные есть)

Архитектура бинарного сериализатора позволяет сделать сериализатор новой версии и добавить сохранение недостающих полей. Но вот что делать с теми данными что уже есть? Написание скрипта для правки этих данных может занять очень много времени. Слишком большой шанс допустить ошибку и похерить данные на проде.

Хотелось бы как-то реализовать в архитектуре логику подгрузки данных, в случае если их не оказалось в бинарной версии. Или например завязаться на версию бинарного сериализатора - если версия старая, то нужно часть данных подсосать из таблиц. Сами сериализаторы реализованы в лучших традициях энтерпрайза.

Собственно никто не сталкивался с подобной проблемой? Может подскажете есть ли какие-то типовые решения?

Comment: много это сколько ? у меня на работе база 190gb запросы идут очень быстро , может проблема в сервере ? может база находится на HDD , а не на SSD и чтение по этому долгое ?

Comment: У нас нет доступа до прода. Точно не могу сказать какой порядок. Но не 200Гб это точно. Обычный запрос на то чтобы поменять тип колонки у одной таблицы с CLOB на BLOB (создаем новую колонку копируем туда значения и удаляем старую) занимал несколько часов. Есть отдельная команда которая занимается оптимизацией базы данных. Так что думаю что все возможные меры по оптимизации предприняты. Но там просто много данных. Собственно такое решение не просто так принято. Вопрос как оптимизировать это сейчас.

Comment: а в чем суть проблемы? Что у вас БД медленная или что вам приходится 2 сериализатора поддерживать?

Comment: Суть проблемы в том что был найден баг, данных там много и сдеать "датафикс" не получится. Мы добавили новую логику в сериализатор, но в старых данных нет нужных нам значений и их можно получить старым сериализатором.  То есть нужен своего рода механизм мерджа. Где в приоритете идет бинарный сериализатор.